# A Tree structure of base and derived class objects in C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have two classes

```
class Base {
   explicit Base();

   virtual void update();
}

class Derived : Base {

  std::shared_ptr<Base> left, right;
   
  explicit Derived(std::shared_ptr<Base> left, std::shared_ptr<Base>);

  virtual void update() override;

  void special_update();

}
```

I can create a Derived object from two pointers to Base class objects. But I would also like to create a Derived object from two pointers to Derived class objects as well. Any good way to do this?

Comment: You can use `dynamic_cast` to check if `left` param in constructor is of `Derived` class or of some other `Base` class.

Comment: Do you know why you're using the `explicit` modifier with your constructors, or do you just always do that?

Comment: Also: from the class names and the shared `update()`, it looks like `Derived` is intended to be a subclass of `Base`. But your code doesn't show that. Is `Derived` supposed to be a subclass of `Base` or not?

Comment: Yes. I do intend to have the derived class derived from Base. I have edited the code.

Comment: @AnthonyMBenedict Do you also intend it to be private inheritance or public inheritance?

Comment: @caleb using explicit often is just a habit (bad one)

Comment: @bitmask I have private members in Base, I use protected inheritance

Comment: @AnthonyMBenedict See my updated answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming** you intend `Derived` to be a class publicly derived from `Base`, you are looking for [`std::static_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) which can convert a `std::shared_ptr` of one type to a `std::shared_ptr` of another type:

```
Derived(std::shared_ptr<Derived> left, std::shared_ptr<Derived> right)
  : Derived(
      std::static_pointer_cast<Base>(left),
      std::static_pointer_cast<Base>(right)) {
}
```

If you didn't **know** that the type will always be convertible to `Base` because of inheritance relations you could also use `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` (e.g. when casting from `Base` to `Derived`).

Also note that you very very likely need to have a `virtual ~Base() {}` if you intend to lug `Derived` objects around in `std::shared_ptr<Base>` objects. Otherwise, you will most likely incur UB.

---

If `Derived` and `Base` are, in fact, completely unrelated then the answer is **no**.

---

If you have private inheritance you have to roll your own version of `static_pointer_cast`:

```
// in Derived:
static std::shared_ptr<Base> static_pointer_cast(std::shared_ptr<Derived> const& r) noexcept {
    return std::shared_ptr<Base>(r, r.get());
}
```

Comment: There is no need to use a cast to convert a derived to a base. `return std::shared_ptr<Base>(r, static_cast<Base*>(r.get()));` won't work, you cannot make two shared pointer that point to the same object withoput knowing abput each othe (you mat want to look at `std::enable_shared_from_this` for that)

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Why do you say this? Note that the first argument to `std::shared_ptr` is `r`, the original object. Have a look at the documentation for `shared_ptr`'s [constructor (8)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the aliasing constructor.